# Can we skip some errors in error log file using log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, error-handling, mule, log4j2

I got an error when I have duplicates, It doesn't effect my application.I want to skip those errors from my error log file. IS it possible to skip specific errors,if possible how can I do that?.I am using mulesoft.

Comment: Which framework you are using for JDBC connection, core-java using Connection class, spring-jdbc?? Please post your data connection code snippet.

Comment: Can you show the code snippet which generates the error messages? something like: logger.error("there are duplicates");
In general, you should simply delete or comment out these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Mule uses SLF4J (3.8.x) as the logging frontend framework and log4j2 for the backend or implementation framework. If the errors appear in the application's log, chances are that you can set that particular category to OFF.

Of course it would be preferable to just ignoring the errors to analyze the root cause (why are there duplicates?).